# Limit of a subsequence

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, sequence

I am trying to calculate limit for a subsequence <${ a }_{ {n  }^{  2} }$> because I was trying to see that limits of sequences and subsequences are both same.

I was able to generate the sum for square values as,

```
N[ Sum[ 1/(n (n + 1)), {n, Table[n^2, {n, 1, 1000}]}]]
```

But I want to know how I shall find limit to a subsequence of square integers.

Answer (score 3):

You can proceed this way (to calculate the sum of the first `k` terms of the subsequence) :

```
Sum[ 1/(n (n + 1)) /. n -> n^2, {n, k}]
```

> ```
> 1/6 (Pi^2 - 3 I PolyGamma[0, 1 - I] + 3 I PolyGamma[0, 1 + I] + 
>      3 I PolyGamma[0, (1 - I) + k] - 3 I PolyGamma[0, (1 + I) + k] 
>      - 6 PolyGamma[1, 1 + k]  )
> ```

and take the limit simply :

```
Limit[ Sum[ 1/(n (n + 1)) /. n -> n^2, {n, k}], k -> Infinity]
```

> ```
>  1/6 (3 + Pi^2 - 3 Pi Coth[Pi])
> ```

numerically :

```
N @ %
```

> ```
> 0.56826
> ```

Comment: actually what the final result here is the sum of the subsequence that I got after running the command I have referred to. I need to find Limit of a sequence whose domain is set of n^2.

Comment: @rafiki Can't you see this is the way to go ?  Perhaps you want simply `Limit[1/(n (n + 1)) /. n -> n^2, n -> Infinity]`.

Comment: If I am not wrong /. is replacement. But there is difference in calculating a sequence on 1/(n(n+1)) and 1/(n^2(n^2+1))...please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @rafiki Subsequence of $n^2$ terms of $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ is $\frac{1}{n^2 (n^2 + 1)}$. What do you mean by calculating of subsequence ?

Comment: subsequence of a sequence belongs to the sequence....it doesn't !

Comment: @rafiki I'm not going to discuss any apparent problems. If you have any questions, please try to expose them as clearly as possible. Of course `Mathematica` cannot understand what you should do.

Comment: Well no doubt I agree with you and that is why I made reference to the theorem regarding equality of limits of sequence and subsequence.

Comment: @rafiki As you should know not every sequence has a limit, but if it has none some of its subsequence can have a limit.

Comment: I think it can't because there is always a term in subsequence that goes beyond nth term of sequence and it the sequence is unbounded than subsequence is too...please provide me with an example for reference.

Comment: @rafiki $(-1)^n$ has no limit, but its subsequence $(-1)^{2n}$ is constant and equal to $1$ while another subsequence $(-1)^{2n + 1}$ is equal to $-1$, so they both have different limits.

Comment: Yes I am aware of it and I was talking in terms of non-oscillatory functions...what my question says is that if I supply this oscillatory function than it shall tell me its limit for odd and even domain if it exists. That's the limit of subsequence I am looking for.